# SharePoint 2013 document callout popup cut off when webpart is a fixed height

Tags: sharepoint-2013

This appears to be a SharePoint 2013 bug.
One of the exciting features of SharePoint 2013 is the Callout.  When you have a list of documents, and you want to learn more about the document without having to open it, you can click the three dots Callout button to get a popup that shows pertinent information about the document.

The problem is this information is being cut off when you apply a fixed height to the webparts properties and the height is not enough to accommodate the popup.

It appears to be due to the webpart being converted to an iFrame when a specific height is applied to it.  I have been unable to find a CSS fix for this.

You can view an image of the issue here: http://www.pixelwonders.com/fixed-height-webpart.jpg

Anyone know how to fix this?

Thank you in advance for your help!

Answer (score 1):

I had a very similar issue. I have a Google Map web part with fixed height and width in a two column layout, with a list on the right. The filter drop down menu would cut off just like what your image shows.

I was able to correct it by adding a script editor  to modify the CSS with overflow: visible !important on both columns. In your image it looks like you have one web part above another, I would think the same rules would apply.

```
<style>
#WebPartWPQ3{
overflow: visible !important;
}
#WebPartWPQ2{
overflow: visible !important;
}
</style>
```